# Mule - Type mismatch for 'map' operator

Tags: mule, mule-component, anypoint-studio

Requirement is to bring CXF service in mule. 
As per my knowledge i tried creating the configuration in mule but getting an error as shown below.

```
Exception while executing: 
        (payload.ns0#ValidateVIN.*ns0#VIN map ((vIN , indexOfVIN) -> {
         ^
Type mismatch for 'map' operator
     found :null, :function
  required :array, :function.
```

Attaching the code below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<mule ... >
    <http:listener-config name="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" host="0.0.0.0" port="9009" basePath="Mule" doc:name="HTTP Listener Configuration"/>
    <cxf:configuration name="Autoprefill_CXF_Configuration" enableMuleSoapHeaders="true" initializeStaticBusInstance="true" doc:name="CXF Configuration"/>
    <flow name="autoprefillFlow">
        <http:listener config-ref="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" path="/VINService" allowedMethods="POST" doc:name="HTTP"/>
        <logger message="#[message.payloadAs(String)]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
        <dw:transform-message doc:name="Transform Message" metadata:id="566ab616-f256-4763-af42-82d4cbbcc277">
            <dw:input-payload mimeType="application/xml"/>
            <dw:set-payload><![CDATA[%dw 1.0
            %output application/xml
            %namespace ns0 http://www.pwc.com/vin
            ---
            {
                ns0#ValidateVIN: {
                    (payload.ns0#ValidateVIN.*ns0#VIN map ((vIN , indexOfVIN) -> {
                        ns0#VIN: vIN
                    }))
                }
            }]]></dw:set-payload>
        </dw:transform-message>
        <cxf:simple-client operation="validateVIN" serviceClass="autoprefill.VINPort" doc:name="CXF"/>
        <logger message="#[message.payloadAs(String)]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
    </flow>
</mule>
```

I tried removing the message transform property, but that time i got the below error

```
java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.util.Collection. Failed to route event via endpoint: org.mule.module.cxf.CxfOutboundMessageProcessor
```

The service is expecting a list of string. Im not sure how that can be done in mule. Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in the `Transform Message` component.

The map function is expecting an array of data (collection of data), but it did not receive any value.

I suggest to check the payload before `Transform Message` component. Perhaps payload is not in expected format. If you can share the payload (or full logs at least) here, I can help you with the transformation.